# App Crashing Upon Startup for Users, Cannot Replicate Errors

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

The update for my app went live the other day, with no problems in testing on various devices and operating systems. However, it is crashing for several of my users upon startup. I am fairly new at reading crash logs. Can someone point me in the right direction as to where to start looking, for this particular crash log? I am hoping that this question will also help others to decipher similar logs. I can post code as necessary, if I have an idea of which code to post.

I have seen a lot of threads where people are encouraging the developer to use NSZombie, etc. Let me reiterate that I cannot replicate this crash on my own, either in the simulator or on any device that I have. This is sent to me from a user, and I have received several that look like it.

I had to pull my app off the app store, and am anxious to get it back up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: D56D112D-A7A5-44C0-AE3A-DE9172B0307D CrashReporter Key:   58cb8875fb20ba07fd89538f0489f0a971488f9e Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1 Process:         MyApp [13747] Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/02DEF31B-0435-4656-BA71-DEC01DCEDB84/MyApp.app/MyApp Identifier:      MyApp Version:         ??? (???) Code Type:       ARM (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-29 07:31:42.137 -0500 OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206) Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed: 
0   MyApp                               0x0012180a 0x91000 + 591882 
1   MyApp                               0x00121a38 0x91000 + 592440 
2   MyApp                           0x000b3cac 0x91000 + 142508 
3   Foundation                      0x3559c92c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 408 
4   CoreFoundation              0x35a56a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
+ 8 
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35a56692 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358 
6   CoreFoundation                  0x35a55268 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200 
7   CoreFoundation                  0x359d849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294 
8   CoreFoundation                  0x359d8366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 
9   GraphicsServices                0x37674432 GSEventRunModal + 130 
10  UIKit                           0x334e4cce UIApplicationMain + 1074 
11  MyApp                               0x00093e48 0x91000 + 11848 
12  MyApp


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x363283a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34912f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34912c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36338cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36328004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x363281fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35a563ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35a55124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x359d849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x359d8366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x318d7c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e4572e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e455e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36338cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36338cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e3fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001ef7a4    r1: 0x001ed9ac      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x003c16a0    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fe8ee2c
    r8: 0x0019b7af    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x001ef698     r11: 0x00000006
    ip: 0x3ed9d1f4    sp: 0x2fe8ee20      lr: 0x326af187      pc: 0x0012180a
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the log first. This will tell you exactly which line of code is causing the problem. A quick search will point you to plenty of discussions on how to do that.

Comment: I dragged the log into Organizer->Library->Device Logs and I clicked re-symbolicate, and this is what I get. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you archive the app when you prepared to send it to Apple? Do you have the dSYM for the app? If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: I did archive it. I don't know if I have the DSYM as I didn't take any special steps beyond archiving. I am showing my green brightly right now, aren't I? Can I get what I need from the archive file? I can run Xcode right now in exactly the same state as when I created the archive - would that possibly help or am I out of luck?

Comment: If you have the archive then you have what you need. The archive includes the dSYM. Do a search on symbolicating crash reports. You'll find much better info than I could type here in a comment. But start with [Apple's TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

Comment: OK, I had just found it from your comment. Thanks so very much.

Comment: I did it and it turns out that that actually is the symbolicated log. I even saw it 'change' from the original log to that when I went back into the Organizer after performing some steps. Can you give me any direction from what you can see from the file?

Comment: That is not a symbolicated crash report. A symbolicated crash report shows method names and filenames with line numbers (at least for your own code). I have no way to know what you are doing wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I will keep trying. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think my symbolification issues have something to do with the fact that I have a space and an apostrophe in my app name. Still trying to get this working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a really hard time symbolicating my crash logs, and I was never able to get it to work without using atos. I am pretty sure that this is because my app name contains a space and an apostrophe. Here is a link to the thread where I was finally able to *manually* get the information I needed using atos (and ultimately some hexadecimal math - ugh).

[Symbolicate Crash Log when App Name Contains Apostrophe and Space (Deployed App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650516/symbolicate-crash-log-when-app-name-contains-apostrophe-and-space-deployed-app)