# Unable to symbolicate crash log

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I am facing some problem in symbolicating my crash log. 
I followed all the steps as answered by naveenshan in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) thread. 
But once I execute the line

`atos -arch armv7 -o 'app name.app'/'app name' 0x0003b508`,

it just throws me back the address 0x0003b508 back on the console.

I am not able to figure out why its not symbolicating my crash log.

I even tried symbolicating by drag and drop my crash log into device logs in my xcode. But even that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Do you have the `.DSYM` files?

Comment: Yes I do. I have the DSYM file, .crash file and my app file all in one folder.

Comment: The thing is, I made an ipa for the app initially for testing and then for symbolicating my crash log, I archived the same build and got my DSYM file. Hope that shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: That probably won't be an issue as long as both apps were built using the same compiler and compiler options.

Comment: For symbolication you need to have the dSYM that was build at the same time as the application that is being installed. Each time the build process will assign the application binary a new UUID which is then used in the crash report. The symbolication process uses that UUID to find the corresponding dSYM package. Now if you build again, that UUID will be different and if the previous dSYM was deleted or cannot be found via Spotlight, symbolication will not work. No matter if the compiler and options are identical!

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the exact dSYM that was generated along the build that is installed on the device and generates the crash report.

Please follow the steps explained in this answer (even though the original problems are not the same, the steps help identify if you have the correct dSYM): [Symbolicate Crash Log when App Name Contains Apostrophe and Space (Deployed App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650516/symbolicate-crash-log-when-app-name-contains-apostrophe-and-space-deployed-app/13660458#13660458)

Executing the line with `atos` you posted, is most likely to return nothing useful, since the address given as a parameter does not have to exist in your app. You have to use a proper address taken from the crash report and calculated properly as detailed here: [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028)

Best approach is the follow the steps written in the first linked post.