# How do I symbolicate a copy/pasted crash report?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, organizer, symbolicatecrash

I have a user who is experiencing a crash using the app store version of an iPhone app.  The crash is not reported via iTunes connect and the user is unable to sync with iTunes and get me the .crash file (they don't have a computer).  The user is, however, able to copy and paste the crash report from the phone under "Settings > general > about > Diagnostics & usage data".

I took this users copied crash report and manually pasted it into a text file and renamed it with the .crash extension.  When I import this manually created .crash report into XCode's Organizer, I am not able to symbolicate it.  I am using the same copy of XCode that generated the app store binary and the ipa is archived and I am able to symbolicate crashes that come from iTunes connect.

Is it expected that the manually created .crash file would not symbolicate or am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

****update**** I am also unable to symbolicate the crash report using the steps here: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports).

****update 2**** Here is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 3A2A3D26-1E44-46AA-9777-658EBBBEDD57
CrashReporter Key:   a9eadbf28904a2c3b4d285c7455db9ae06a5a555
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:         MyApp [1180]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0B09C692-7C36-4398-AC77-4217401E0FC/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-12 18:45:15.066 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.1 (10B143)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.company.MyApp failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.800 (user 0.800, system 0.000), 4% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.004, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3b39ce98 0x3b39c000 + 3736
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3b2d7c16 0x3b2d2000 + 23574
2   CoreData                          0x330b9304 0x32f4d000 + 1491716
3   CoreData                          0x330a75f6 0x32f4d000 + 1418742
4   CoreData                          0x32f56a3e 0x32f4d000 + 39486
5   MyApp                          0x000f17b8 0xef000 + 10168
6   MyApp                          0x000f11b4 0xef000 + 8628
7   MyApp                          0x000f2f2c 0xef000 + 16172
8   MyApp                          0x0010c9c6 0xef000 + 121286
9   MyApp                          0x0010cb3c 0xef000 + 121660
10  UIKit                             0x3503e2f0 0x34fd4000 + 434928
11  UIKit                             0x3505b0b0 0x34fd4000 + 553136
12  UIKit                             0x3503e2f0 0x34fd4000 + 434928
13  UIKit                             0x3505af64 0x34fd4000 + 552804
14  UIKit                             0x3505aef0 0x34fd4000 + 552688
15  UIKit                             0x34fe0a82 0x34fd4000 + 51842
16  CoreFoundation                    0x3319d93e 0x33106000 + 620862
17  CoreFoundation                    0x3319bc34 0x33106000 + 613428
18  CoreFoundation                    0x3319bf8e 0x33106000 + 614286
19  CoreFoundation                    0x3310f238 0x33106000 + 37432
20  CoreFoundation                    0x3310f0c4 0x33106000 + 37060
21  GraphicsServices                  0x36ced336 0x36ce8000 + 21302
22  UIKit                             0x3502b2b4 0x34fd4000 + 357044
23  MyApp                          0x000f0d16 0xef000 + 7446
24  MyApp                          0x000f0ccc 0xef000 + 7372

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3b39d5d0 0x3b39c000 + 5584
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3b2d8d22 0x3b2d2000 + 27938
2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3b2d4374 0x3b2d2000 + 9076

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3b39ce30 0x3b39c000 + 3632
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3b39cfd0 0x3b39c000 + 4048
2   CoreFoundation                    0x3319d2b6 0x33106000 + 619190
3   CoreFoundation                    0x3319c02c 0x33106000 + 614444
4   CoreFoundation                    0x3310f238 0x33106000 + 37432
5   CoreFoundation                    0x3310f0c4 0x33106000 + 37060
6   WebCore                           0x3910e390 0x39104000 + 41872
7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3b3060de 0x3b2f5000 + 69854
8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3b305fa4 0x3b2f5000 + 69540

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
   0xef000 -   0x134fff +MyApp armv7s  <1c1233075bd63f039b9f71f66cc1b1d3> /var/mobile/Applications/0B09C692-7C36-4398-AC77-A4217401E0FC/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x2fe7f000 - 0x2fe9ffff  dyld armv7s  <44ac9ef7642f3ba7943f6451887d3af5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x322dd000 - 0x323c3fff  AVFoundation armv7s  <56f22385ccb73e31863f1fa9e0b621dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x323c4000 - 0x323c4fff  Accelerate armv7s  <f4e8c4c464953429ab6bd3160aadd176> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x323c5000 - 0x32502fff  vImage armv7s  <49d3cf19d0a23f4d836fc313e5fd6bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x32503000 - 0x325effff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <584e045442be39fc847ffe1a5e4c99b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x325f0000 - 0x328a6fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <30a3e7dd8c603a9d81b5e42704ba5971> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x328a7000 - 0x328fffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <936354553eb93d2dafa76ffcad65f9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32900000 - 0x32912fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <5fae8715a0403315bb1991b79677f916> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x32913000 - 0x32913fff  vecLib armv7s  <30275ee8819331229ba21256d7b94596> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32914000 - 0x32925fff  Accounts armv7s  <df3255c62b0239f4995bc14ea79f106b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x32927000 - 0x3298bfff  AddressBook armv7s  <ea949de12ca93a6a96ef80d0cb4d9231> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3298c000 - 0x32a46fff  AddressBookUI armv7s  <b25d9a6111d53dc48d8e5e9a30c362ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32b93000 - 0x32e1cfff  AudioToolbox armv7s  <8b8ef592d59f371783933b446a3e0e67> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32e1d000 - 0x32ee2fff  CFNetwork armv7s  <ef41814d8641319c96cdeb1264d2d150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32ee3000 - 0x32f39fff  CoreAudio armv7s  <19aa715b19a93a5c8563dbc706e899be> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32f4d000 - 0x33105fff  CoreData armv7s  <dee36bfc0c213492983c73d7bd83a27d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x33106000 - 0x33238fff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <bd8e6c9f94b43e3d9af96a0f03ff3011> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33239000 - 0x33372fff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <ef057fe1c715314cabf133ec26fa718c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33374000 - 0x333affff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <163d7f8309a6350399bbb1fef6cde32c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33593000 - 0x335aefff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <387d00a9ed55303b8936459a99869e07> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x335af000 - 0x33664fff  CoreImage armv7s  <7d7cd7998a113ed9b483e7dc9f388b05> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33665000 - 0x336bdfff  CoreLocation armv7s  <94c4fa04ba3c3f5e9d17d75074985ce9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x336f2000 - 0x33757fff  CoreMedia armv7s  <526b25ed6f4e31b790553bd80d46fec7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33758000 - 0x337e0fff  CoreMotion armv7s  <d71e40c801423c9cbb31a188120a1c58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x337e1000 - 0x33837fff  CoreTelephony armv7s  <bdf5f32e89073773a7fdbcc87fc6b412> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33838000 - 0x3389afff  CoreText armv7s  <a01bc990cb483e828f7c3e08cd446daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3389b000 - 0x338aafff  CoreVideo armv7s  <851591a704dc344aa2fc397094b4c622> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x338ab000 - 0x3395ffff  EventKit armv7s  <6282cd57cf6233359489a46554a5bb15> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x33a2f000 - 0x33bf2fff  Foundation armv7s  <0f73c35ada563c0bb2ce402d282faefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33dad000 - 0x33df6fff  IOKit armv7s  <4e5e55f27bbb35bab7af348997bfac17> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33df7000 - 0x33fcffff  ImageIO armv7s  <e04300f6e6b232ce8a02139d8f18dfdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34049000 - 0x341e3fff  MediaPlayer armv7s  <3328573c20643b02806559249c749793> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x341e4000 - 0x3445efff  MediaToolbox armv7s  <1b36b1b41eca35989d2e822240a769cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3445f000 - 0x344e5fff  MessageUI armv7s  <2fbfe798afe130cba7360b49d0ad487c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x344e6000 - 0x3453ffff  MobileCoreServices armv7s  <b0d1162a8ab03529bb90e416895b568a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3462f000 - 0x34636fff  OpenGLES armv7s  <c9c8f7cbfbe5397382286b878bdf143c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34638000 - 0x34638fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <b7d1ddfeb0db36d6af7293fa625b12be> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3463c000 - 0x3463efff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <8bcac434962435a895fa0b0a3a33b7a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3463f000 - 0x34643fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <272a9de67f6632c3aebbe2407cfe716b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34644000 - 0x34683fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <3a444257935236fab123e46e617c7a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34d83000 - 0x34e97fff  QuartzCore armv7s  <b28fd354be3c38a2965e6368fa35e0c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34e98000 - 0x34ee4fff  QuickLook armv7s  <2350b507fe1b3a1a94d2824e34649b36> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x34ee5000 - 0x34f13fff  Security armv7s  <e1fcc8913eba360c868f51558a01cf24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34f92000 - 0x34fd1fff  SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0fb8d4a2fa8f30ce837e068a046e466b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34fd4000 - 0x35527fff  UIKit armv7s  <62bee9294ca13738bd7ff14365dc8561> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35528000 - 0x35567fff  VideoToolbox armv7s  <57487f6e3c38304ab0aa14dd16043f5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x357fd000 - 0x35809fff  AccountSettings armv7s  <c4b7436e8ea33ffd9805905f262e4479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35850000 - 0x35853fff  ActorKit armv7s  <3aa66a29d9343626baa9d63d1a6efc14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x35855000 - 0x35858fff  AggregateDictionary armv7s  <6916a617625e3800bbb75a34294f4d13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x35941000 - 0x35954fff  AirTraffic armv7s  <e2261ffe1d803bc6bbed23191c848bad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x35c84000 - 0x35cbffff  AppSupport armv7s  <7d6122cb42363dc981247c926e637a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x35cc0000 - 0x35ce4fff  AppleAccount armv7s  <668e780f91163aaca1c36294d702ae50> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x35cf1000 - 0x35cfefff  ApplePushService armv7s  <4638fab5719a3007beca5a798aa69e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x35d32000 - 0x35d3bfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <ec78d21573a23c34b6cec05ba56928f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x35d6a000 - 0x35d81fff  BackBoardServices armv7s  <36f93cef9f6830f490fe00818bcffa2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x35d8b000 - 0x35daffff  Bom armv7s  <f35bf1c1b24a3742847383801ac37505> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35e2f000 - 0x35e36fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <e308f6a4f4bf3749b56bd6ff4dd8b30a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35e37000 - 0x35f01fff  Celestial armv7s  <a2f7438cb5163307a04d78bc2b8a86a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35f0e000 - 0x35f12fff  CertUI armv7s  <98e5a166bb473fa9b2840dfdad00580a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x35fb8000 - 0x35fd1fff  ChunkingLibrary armv7s  <cddc1ecde9723802ae441d20fe604c7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x35fe5000 - 0x35feafff  CommonUtilities armv7s  <eb0b7e85b57e32f38dc498c0ee97aa7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x3606f000 - 0x3609ffff  ContentIndex armv7s  <7a304e48f6213864820081df620939e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x36292000 - 0x362affff  CoreServicesInternal armv7s  <373f1c58aee834698fb2e7b18660e870> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x362b0000 - 0x362b1fff  CoreSurface armv7s  <55826212d8b4352b87d80f93bc9b25c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3631e000 - 0x36323fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <3b190badb14f3771b353fcd829719c80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36324000 - 0x36360fff  DataAccess armv7s  <7dcaa9fce0213cbead487fcd0980bd59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x364f5000 - 0x36507fff  DataAccessExpress armv7s  <05ed021492f2394f9d43216d8b963665> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36546000 - 0x36547fff  DataMigration armv7s  <5e7169ad01853bd0ba0f66648a67a010> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3654a000 - 0x36563fff  DictionaryServices armv7s  <27298e235f2c35938e1033517b1196a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3656b000 - 0x36583fff  EAP8021X armv7s  <bff91efbc6ba369089b699bb50191905> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x36592000 - 0x36596fff  FTClientServices armv7s  <c158c4281a2e31d7913d9f8b0fb4417c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x36597000 - 0x365d5fff  FTServices armv7s  <71ca9253aee730eca6c4ca3210861a2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x365d6000 - 0x369e9fff  FaceCoreLight armv7s  <432cbaeb84743441b9286532bc36c96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x36be1000 - 0x36bedfff  GenerationalStorage armv7s  <4e1afa8de682332ba6a042a6000c636e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x36bee000 - 0x36ce7fff  GeoServices armv7s  <f2a20efae86a30cb8210550de0280ce7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36ce8000 - 0x36cf3fff  GraphicsServices armv7s  <44b33c403523309c9e930818c7fced34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36d62000 - 0x36dddfff  HomeSharing armv7s  <137c1fbc6a843d369038348255635111> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x36dde000 - 0x36de8fff  IAP armv7s  <f43af100e43c3d1fac19a86cb7665c18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x36ea0000 - 0x36f18fff  IMCore armv7s  <a212f1303a4f3d47aaf21078f172e4bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x36fdf000 - 0x3702bfff  IMFoundation armv7s  <55151f53b10934c3a5faac54e354f3f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x37032000 - 0x37033fff  IOAccelerator armv7s  <832913083f7f347fba1340263ff13b52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x37034000 - 0x37039fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <828a36a2325738bb8f2d4b97730d253a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3703a000 - 0x3703efff  IOSurface armv7s  <9925fbc4a08d3a17b72ac807cbbba8ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x37088000 - 0x3722ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7s  <f7be721eee903a93a7de361e5627445e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x37255000 - 0x3725ffff  Librarian armv7s  <24168aa764823064a5b151a56a413c8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x37260000 - 0x37296fff  MIME armv7s  <3f8dc502266237c6809c4d33b6e359ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x372d5000 - 0x372dffff  MailServices armv7s  <737ace3c1c7c3ec6923095f3beadb4b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x372fb000 - 0x37353fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <b147c2d6f0283d988099706a2a404280> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x37354000 - 0x37359fff  Marco armv7s  <53ab26b3197135a781d55819fd80f032> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3736a000 - 0x373e0fff  MediaControlSender armv7s  <29ff7ec2b02d36ec8bf6db33c3a4ba8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x373e1000 - 0x373eafff  MediaRemote armv7s  <0dc7c7c324d33af8b2f7d57f41123de9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x3745d000 - 0x37516fff  Message armv7s  <9ebc49dae1293bf8bbad64153932c756> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3751f000 - 0x37521fff  MessageSupport armv7s  <874f2566017b3931b4595c63d6f77098> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x3752a000 - 0x37557fff  MobileAsset armv7s  <e3217ead58d5390395de360b3ca3a10a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x37584000 - 0x37593fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7s  <ed43d4db46a43db0976eeac5f3bc77a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3759c000 - 0x3759ffff  MobileInstallation armv7s  <7cbe167946123bbea56ae58208e09762> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x375a0000 - 0x375a6fff  MobileKeyBag armv7s  <5c7d50e11eb537ae89ea12cb7ddd3935> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x375df000 - 0x37602fff  MobileSync armv7s  <8ea08ca56ead3d77bba046811a917f79> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x37603000 - 0x37606fff  MobileSystemServices armv7s  <5796fff2895f38e4b0f844269d4fbae5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x3761e000 - 0x37627fff  MobileWiFi armv7s  <e9ae11c07476390d9598c861658cee7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x37641000 - 0x37785fff  MusicLibrary armv7s  <057b076c74fd31b590bccc9b64d7f5cb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3779d000 - 0x377b6fff  Notes armv7s  <de760fe287ee3346b61c4f4e701278f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x377b7000 - 0x377b9fff  OAuth armv7s  <8e91174312e43ca9ac07d91d16b32d15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x37ede000 - 0x37f02fff  OpenCL armv7s  <87637dacbb3c3e029120369438e96fcf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x38264000 - 0x38281fff  PersistentConnection armv7s  <c5164e016fa6340fbce9251278385105> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x38517000 - 0x3853ffff  PrintKit armv7s  <7109f645a9ca3a4997b4172aed228723> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x38540000 - 0x385b4fff  ProofReader armv7s  <e391e8d141c5352d978e5fde23afaaad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x385b5000 - 0x385bdfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <edc3f72bf38c3d81954ac85f489a17e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x386f9000 - 0x3870afff  SpringBoardServices armv7s  <5b94e9a529753052acde16c21e9d2566> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3876c000 - 0x38847fff  StoreServices armv7s  <e465f24460ff3764b4fc95ebd44b2fe3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x38895000 - 0x38897fff  TCC armv7s  <95c2aa492cc03862bd7bbfae6fa62b1b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x388b6000 - 0x388c3fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <aa759d908b903f978ab6803b7947e524> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x38d48000 - 0x38de8fff  UIFoundation armv7s  <e3a40cee28653c4485a4918016ff2b8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x38de9000 - 0x38e01fff  Ubiquity armv7s  <99c7f2772cd63700aae2671b0b153cfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Ubiquity
0x390e4000 - 0x39103fff  WebBookmarks armv7s  <ab55332c13da33fd825ea6204338fe19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x39104000 - 0x39a34fff  WebCore armv7s  <f99b83bec11b331ab69194120917a7df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x39a35000 - 0x39b11fff  WebKit armv7s  <02c32fdddbdc39b1848b721658a2fa51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x39bbc000 - 0x39bc3fff  XPCObjects armv7s  <e6846a96a21d382f9fffd6a4536c0aa7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x39d16000 - 0x39d51fff  iCalendar armv7s  <bcc081bffdae3daea0f7d7db18ed80e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x39e67000 - 0x39e9ffff  iTunesStore armv7s  <10c8c7e5c9f43f75af5b30fc2389c1a2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x3a72d000 - 0x3a733fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <9111bc894a4f3ef683f5ef4d699a861b> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3a734000 - 0x3a74afff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <770ebb2f7d9a35749e6da5d1980c244f> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3a762000 - 0x3a76efff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <efddaaea8d87321a80d4a6d3f9607a80> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3a780000 - 0x3a780fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <12daef214fd234158028c97c22dc5cca> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3a8a2000 - 0x3a8aefff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <0f4a8d65b05a364abca1a97e2ae72cb5> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3a8af000 - 0x3a8b8fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <f54b70863d9c3751bb59253b1cb4c706> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3a8b9000 - 0x3a904fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <3beff5a5233b3f51ab2fc748b68e9519> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3a905000 - 0x3a918fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <f47a5c7bc24c3e4fa73f11b61af635da> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3a949000 - 0x3aa36fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <81d6972465103fa3b85b4125f0ad33f1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3aa37000 - 0x3ab80fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <642482cfc34a3a3b97bd731258dcdc6a> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3ab88000 - 0x3ab88fff  liblangid.dylib armv7s  <ffb53baa33ba3642a55737311f17a672> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3ab8b000 - 0x3ab92fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <dbd4f278c71b3f219da3e895b1f6ac80> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3ae73000 - 0x3ae88fff  libmis.dylib armv7s  <8f0712b99e8e3f5e998f0240f75bb5ba> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3aeb1000 - 0x3afaffff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <1d499765d38c3c8fa92b363f529a02dd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3b073000 - 0x3b088fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <3f7be9d397d63b8e931d21bd5f49b0eb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3b0ad000 - 0x3b133fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <758898189dca32a5a19e5200b8952110> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3b134000 - 0x3b180fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <249e8ca1717b370287bb556bbd96e303> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3b181000 - 0x3b1a7fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <96b463f0ffa0344699fce4d48aa623bc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3b1ab000 - 0x3b258fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <e87724e212573773a60bc56815cec706> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3b259000 - 0x3b279fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <c52fbe01ce7b35c799630e97e8f1318b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3b27a000 - 0x3b286fff  libz.1.dylib armv7s  <b64a5c1989ba3ba4aafae83d841f9496> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3b287000 - 0x3b28afff  libcache.dylib armv7s  <911ce99a94623ef1ae1ea786055fd558> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3b28b000 - 0x3b291fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <33140a5fa3fb3e5e8c6bb19bc0e21c5c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3b292000 - 0x3b294fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <cd17f0ee3dbc38f99910d12a6056bf5a> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3b295000 - 0x3b29afff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <5e733170766430eeaa4e7784e3c7555c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3b29b000 - 0x3b2d1fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <a15c807dcb003ad69810546a578774d9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3b2d2000 - 0x3b2e2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <247a388103633e17b24be038eac612c0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3b2e3000 - 0x3b2e4fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7s  <f873dd712561350096b9452bf1fc4078> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3b2e5000 - 0x3b2e6fff  libdyld.dylib armv7s  <15676e2ee1423f598907ff49fcede85b> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3b2e7000 - 0x3b2e7fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <b0a1a911d4853feba44133e9ce499bc9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3b2e8000 - 0x3b2edfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <69dd64aba1413e75967cd4ad0afa2c15> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3b2ee000 - 0x3b2f1fff  libmacho.dylib armv7s  <5905b311c6fb376388e56a991bb3193d> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3b2f2000 - 0x3b2f3fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <b40e964d7c563296b38625bc7082d6a8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3b2f4000 - 0x3b2f4fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <77a9976b82b73796a0bbc9783929a1e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3b2f5000 - 0x3b37bfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <11bcf1060ec63c8b909a452e6f79be08> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3b37c000 - 0x3b382fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <94fab309ed9b35cdbc075cdda221bc70> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3b383000 - 0x3b39bfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <195d8eeb7c3f31bd916c0b5611abc0e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3b39c000 - 0x3b3b2fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <79bea3ebfda132baba8f5b0ad6ab95f5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3b3b3000 - 0x3b3cffff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <faafc8292d4935c4a78233e1d0879e13> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3b3d0000 - 0x3b3defff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <137f48e279a83d7496659c8e3d3729d4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3b3df000 - 0x3b3e6fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <df14146497cb3fa0a002eedbed49da65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3b3e7000 - 0x3b3e8fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <85e91e99abc03db88eddc665424090b4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3b3e9000 - 0x3b3e9fff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <3b7ec561dbec3a199f09ea08a64e76ee> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3b3ea000 - 0x3b3fffff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <0562a59bdf8d3f7783e93f35d7e724a8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

****update 3**** updated with dwarfdump commands suggested below

```
moliveira-> dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 208F2C67-493A-3DC7-AA74-AE08985CFC7C (armv7) MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 1C123307-5BD6-3F03-9B9F-71F66CC1B1D3 (12-11) MyApp.app/MyApp
[~/Desktop/symbolicate]
moliveira-> dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app.dSYM
UUID: 208F2C67-493A-3DC7-AA74-AE08985CFC7C (armv7) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
UUID: 1C123307-5BD6-3F03-9B9F-71F66CC1B1D3 (12-11) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
```

Comment: Does it appear to be a complete and proper crash report? Can you symbolicate other crash reports for the same app?

Comment: Yes, the crash report looks similar to others I have received via iTunes connect and I am able to symbolicate the reports I have received that way.  It seems to be this copy/pasted version that is giving me the trouble.

Comment: Look at the "OS Version:" line near the top of the report. Is the version one that you have in your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` folder on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I do have the version (6.1) in the folder you indicated.  Interestingly, I am able to symbolicate crash logs from version 6.0.1 which is *not* in the directory but not this crash (which is happening on a version 6.1 device).

Comment: You should paste the report in here so we can actually have a look. Anything else is guessing in the wild.

Comment: Ok - I have updated the question with the crash report.

Comment: the crash log says: the application terminated by the iOS, because the application takes too long to launch or terminate or respond to any system events. you probably have an infinite loop or you block the main thread with a long process somewhere in the app.

Comment: I've removed all the extraneous newlines. If that was there in the report you tried to symbolicate, try again now.

Comment: @tc.: I think you shouldn't fix the question, but provide an answer instead. Because you changed the question, the response from Kerni below ("The report will not be symbolicated, because the stack frames of the threads are not formatted correctly!") doesn't make sense until one looks into the history of the question and finds out that the question(!) was corrected after Kerni wrote the comment. I think it is clearer if the question still contains the problem and the solution is in the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have the exact dSYM that was generated along the build that is installed on the device and generated the crash report.

Some background information and steps to go through to identify the reason why symbolication won't work can be found here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/how-tos-faq/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems

In addition, you might want to be more specific when saying:

> When I import this manually created .crash report into XCode's Organizer, I am not able to symbolicate it.

How does the crash report look like after symbolication? Please post the full report.

Using the same Xcode that generated the app store binary is irrelevant, as said above you need the dSYM that has been generated alongside the app binary. And that dSYM has be accessible via spotlight, as the above linked article explains.

The steps explained in [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) do not always work. See this post for more details on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810920/474794

**Update:** The report will not be symbolicated, because the stack frames of the threads are not formatted correctly! The lines with the 2 hex addresses, the + sign and the number in the end have to be at the end of the line above. So go into each of those lines hit the backspace/delete key to move it up and save. (don't delete the tab after the library/binary name!) Then symbolication should work. Or use this edited one: http://pastebin.com/L9r6PTXr

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The crash report come out of symbolicate looking exactly the same.  There is no partial symbolication.  I am able to symbolicate other crash reports using the same technique from the post I sent:  namely, I copy the .app, dsym, and crash into a folder and run the symbolicate script from the terminal.  I will look through the links you sent to see if I can get any further.

Comment: I followed the instructions on your first link and this was the output.  Note there is a UUID that matches the crash report but it is not the "armv7" entry:

moliveira-> dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 208F2C67-493A-3DC7-AA74-AE08985CFC7C (armv7) MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 1C123307-5BD6-3F03-9B9F-71F66CC1B1D3 (12-11) MyApp.app/MyApp
[~/Desktop/symbolicate]
moliveira-> dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app.dSYM
UUID: 208F2C67-493A-3DC7-AA74-AE08985CFC7C (armv7) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
UUID: 1C123307-5BD6-3F03-9B9F-71F66CC1B1D3 (12-11) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp

Comment: The report will not be symbolicated, because the stack frames of the threads are not formatted correctly! The lines with the 2 hex addresses, the + sign and the number in the end have to be at the end of the line above. So go into each of those lines hit the backspace/delete key to move it up and save. (don't delete the tab after the library/binary name!) Then symbolication should work. Or use this edited one: http://pastebin.com/L9r6PTXr

Comment: That was the problem!  Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73679651/7769239

Answer (score 7):

One way to symbolicate a crash log is to run the following command on terminal:

**xcrun atos -o MyApp.app/MyApp -arch armv7 -l 0xb7000 -f MyApp.crash**

Replace the example hexadecimal number(0xb700) in the command above with the base load address.
Base load address is the first memory address in the line immediately after

*"Binary Images:"*

To get the .app file:

1. Right click on the xcarchive file and select *Show Package Contents*
2. The .app file is in the *Products/Applications* directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the question [How to Manually Symbolicate iOS Crash to View Crash Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832900/how-to-manually-symbolicate-ios-crash-to-view-crash-logs)

A plugin is available for Xcode under the Product menu. This plugin is available through [Alcatraz package manager](https://libraries.io/alcatraz) or can be directly downloaded [from github](https://github.com/MaheshRS/symbolication-plugin).

This plugin internally incorporates a shell script that does the set up of running the following commands for manual crash symbolication.

1. Set an alias to symbolicatecrash.pl perl script

> alias
>   symbolicatecrash='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash'

2. To find symbolicatecrash, should it differ from the alias above:

> find /Applications/Xcode.app -name symbolicatecrash -type f

3. Set the DEVELOPER_DIR variable:

> export DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

4. With the dSYM the crash can be symbolicates as:

> symbolicatecrash /path/to/MyApp_2012-10-01_Device.crash
>   /path/to/MyApp.app.dSYM.