# App Crashes Random TestFlight Users After Download

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, provisioning-profile, testflight

We recently started using `TestFlight` for distributing our apps to our testers to make things easier. However, a handful of our testers have had the game crash, not on load, but after they move to a new scene in the game.

We believe that this isn't an issue to the game crashing, but something to do with `TestFlight`. The same users on another project experienced the same thing. I have the same devices and iOS version as them and mine doesn't seem to crash when downloaded from `TestFlight`. The same goes for a few other testers who are running the same devices and iOS versions as those who are crashing.

Of course, when not getting the build form `TestFlight`, those testers' apps do not crash.

I have a feeling it may have something to do with the provisioning profile or similar not having their device ID's on the app, but I have made sure that when compiling the `.IPA` that it's using the correct profile and certificates.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the exact solution to your problems, but I can confirm that TestFlight ad-hoc distribution has indeed some conflicts. I wrote and tested an app and it worked flawlessly on my device. I put it on TestFlight and few people had problems with it (microphone did not work). I tested the app on same devices without any code changes, but directly from Xcode and it worked.

Comment: Where is the actual crash report? Without the crash report nothing can be said other than continuing pure (and false) speculation! All Testflight and other similar services do is create a plist file, that points to the actual ipa that you uploaded. The ipa is never ever touched or changed in any way (signing would fail otherwise!). iOS takes that file to download the ipa and install it. If the provisioning profile does not contain the device, iOS would *NOT* install the app!

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping someone might have some sort of answer. It's a bit frustrating since some people I'm working with have clients/partners they need to get their apps to, on top of their testers.

Comment: @Kerni I'm thinking it might be a problem of the Provisioning Profile itself, although it seems like it decides to install the app, just crashes after the scene changes.

Comment: You need to get the crash report. Again, if there is a problem with the profile the app would not install and not start! If Testflight doesn't give you any crash report, ask the user to check on the actual device and send that over. Check this question and answer on how to get the report directly from the device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964024/how-do-i-symbolicate-a-copy-pasted-crash-report

Comment: I'll attempt to get the crash report. It's a bit hard since I don't have instant access to the devices that are crashing since they are remote, but I can try to get them. I remember looking at them and didn't find much useful in terms of why they are crashing since our apps are built within Unity and there wasn't any relavent information towards the app itself.

Comment: As far as I know, Unity has/had quite a few places in the library where it simply quits the app because of an unknown state or whatever situation they decided to do that. The crash report should tell you more. It is far more likely that they app has a bug that causes the crash or unity simply killing itself than there being a problem because of the provisioning profile. Again, if you install the app directly, the provisioning profile is identical as when installing it OTA. You are assumptions are most likely (99.9% IMHO) wrong. Always check the crash report first.

Comment: I'd also suggest having your testers download a free console app that can look at their log file.  I use one from "Thezi Studios" that has been a life saver when I'm away from the computer.

Comment: Have you checked the testflight intern crash report? i found out that in some cases the user has to delete all invalid profiles from the iphone under settings/general/profile.... p.s. i'm not shure if its general because i have currently no eng. language in use.